# Postgres calculated columns from joins

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following table:

```
id | underlying | option_symbol | option_type | expiration_date | strike | mid |
```

I need to perform calculations on joined fields and use those calculated fields for further sorting.

Here is a try to what I mean:

```
SELECT  a.underlying, 
a.expiration_date, 
(a.strike - b.strike) as spread_profit, 
(a.mid - b.mid) as spread_distance, 
(spread_distance - spread_profit) as spread_max_loss,
(spread_profit / spread_max_loss) as spread_profit_ratio
FROM option_data a
JOIN option_data b ON a.underlying = b.underlying AND a.expiration_date = b.expiration_date
WHERE a.option_type = 'put' 
AND b.option_type = 'call'
AND a.expiration_date <= '2017-10-31' 
group by a.underlying, a.expiration_date order by spread_profit_ratio desc
```

What should be the right way to formulate this query?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to substitute the whole expressions, like

```
SELECT ...,
   (a.strike - b.strike) AS spread_profit, 
   (a.mid - b.mid) AS spread_distance, 
   (a.mid - b.mid - a.strike + b.strike) AS spread_max_loss,
   ((a.strike - b.strike) / (a.mid - b.mid - a.strike + b.strike))
      AS spread_profit_ratio
...
```

The same holds for the `ORDER BY` clause, but you can use the shortcut `ORDER BY 6` to sort by the sixth `SELECT` list item.

If that is too cumbersome, you can use subselects:

```
SELECT underlying, 
       expiration_date,
       spread_profit, 
       spread_distance,
       spread_max_loss,
       spread_profit / spread_max_loss AS spread_profit_ratio
FROM (SELECT underlying, 
             expiration_date,
             spread_profit, 
             spread_distance,
             (spread_distance - spread_profit) AS spread_max_loss
      FROM (SELECT a.underlying, 
                   a.expiration_date,
                   (a.strike - b.strike) as spread_profit, 
                   (a.mid - b.mid) as spread_distance
            FROM ...
           ) sub_1
     ) sub_2
WHERE ...
ORDER BY spread_profit_ratio DESC;
```

It's your choice!

Comment: Right. But in this cases I often prefer to use a CTE. Ex: `with myCTE as (select <some_omplex_expr> as calculated, ... form ... where ...) select calculated, someFn(calculated) * 23 as someOtherCalc, ... from myCTE`

Comment: Perhaps that will make the query more readable, but since [CTEs are optimization fences](https://blog.2ndquadrant.com/postgresql-ctes-are-optimization-fences/), the performance may suffer.